# Showing relation table fields with filters in yii2

Tags: filter, yii2, has-many, yii2-basic-app

I'm showing has many relation table value in my girdview as follows

```
[
    'attribute' => 'Resume Title',
    'value'     => function($model, $key, $index) {
        return implode(\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(
             $model->jobSeekerProfiles, 
            'job_seeker_profile_id', 
            'resume_title'
        ));
    },
],
```

my table relation is

```
public function getJobSeekerProfiles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(JobSeekerProfile::className(), ['user_id' => 'user_id']);
}
```

But how to make this column with filter and sortable ?

Comment: useful for you http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview/

Comment: @jithin see my edits,the link you have provided is much helpful on `Hasone` .I am trying it with `HasMany` :)

Comment: You have to consider that the amount of columns could vary for each row. Have you thought about this? What is you assumption?

Comment: @robsch Sorry,I dont understand your comment.could you pls brief

Comment: I was wrong, sorry. However, one entry may consist of several items. Do you expect that they get sorted as well? Usually, sorting is about the rows in a GridView.

Comment: Usually, sorting is about the rows in a GridView.// You mean we cant sort the table-2 values in table-1 ??

Comment: It's not impossible. Was that your goal? Or would you like sort both at the same time? I'm not sure if I can provide an answer. But you need to clarify those things anyway (edit you question - don't add this in the comments, please) otherwise no one can help you as you need it.

Comment: ok. Wheather the Filters possible?

Comment: Also not impossible. But not out of the box. You have to modify the search model. Did you have a look into the [guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#filtering-data)?

Comment: See my question is Simple.Want to combinly show two tables data in single grid.